# Is it possible to force a system locale to a program?

Tags: windows, locale

This question is related and similar to this other question: [Is it possible to set the language or locale of a Windows program at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770325/is-it-possible-to-set-the-language-or-locale-of-a-windows-program-at-runtime)

I have several programs compiled which have a specific hard coded locale which ouput the short months with a dot example: Jan. 24. I want to know if it is possible to specify or force the system locale on that program or change the locale at runtime.

Comment: I'm sure there are many ways to randomly break applications. Why are you trying to do it one particular way?

Comment: The app that I want to force produces a Folder with the short month for example Jan., with the dot, I want to make the app produce the folder without the dot, which happens because of the locale it has.

Comment: Do you know that it's a hardcoded Windows locale that's causing this?  Are you sure the program relies on a Windows API to generate those date strings?  It seems plausible that they just have their own date-to-string functions that disregard the locale.

Comment: If any locale is affecting this, it's likely the current user locale, or maybe the thread locale, but not the system locale. The system locale is rarely used, except as the default basis for the system ANSI/OEM codepages, and even that isn't set in stone as the system ANSI/OEM codepages can be independently set in the registry. Anyway, you probably don't want to override the user locale in most cases. That's the user's choice, not yours. However, for directory names I would use the invariant locale instead of the user locale to ensure it's consistent for all users.