# Different language in PowerShell variable in script performing in Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

- 

Hello! 
I have task in playbook which running code in powershell

```
---
- name: Include vars 
  include_vars:
    file: "global.yml"

- name: Create failover cluster
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ domain.domain_admin }}"
  become_flags: logon_type=interactive logon_flags=with_profile
  become_method: runas
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ domain.password }}"
  win_shell: |
        ## Adding Witcher Disk
        $Quorum_disk = (Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemLabel -eq "Quorum"} | Get-Partition | Get-Disk).Number
        $CLuster_Quorum = (Get-ClusterAvailableDisk | Where-Object {$_.Number -eq $Quorum_disk}).Name
        $CLuster_Quorum >> C:\1.txt
        Get-Culture >> C:\1.txt
        Get-ClusterAvailableDisk | Where {$_.Number -eq $Quorum_disk} | Add-ClusterDisk
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1500
        Set-ClusterQuorum -DiskWitness $CLuster_Quorum
```

In $CLuster_Quorum I have name of disk. When I run this code on local server in Powershell ISE, variable contains the Russian symbols and all works perfect. Ansible put value in variable on English language and task crashes. I tried to execute this code in separate file, using win_comand with the same issue. Get-Culture says me that Ansible use follow regional settings:
LCID - 1049
Name - ru-RU
DisplayName - Russian (Russia)

Has anyone faced issue like this ? 
I am working with PowerShell 4.0 and Windows Server 2012R2. Ansible has version 2.9 and installed on Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you in advance !

Error Messaage

> "stderr":  "Set-ClusterQuorum : An error occurred opening resource
> 'Cluster Disk 1'line:15 char:5      Set-ClusterQuorum -DiskWitness
> $CLuster_Quorum       CategoryInfo                ObjectNotFound: (:)
> [Set-ClusterQuorum], ClusterCmdletException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.SetClusterQuorumCommand",
> "stderr_lines": ["Set-ClusterQuorum : An error occurred opening
> resource 'Cluster Disk 1'.", "At line:15 char:5",    Set-ClusterQuorum
> -DiskWitness $CLuster_Quorum", CategoryInfo,              ObjectNotFound: (:) [Set-ClusterQuorum], ClusterCmdletException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.SetClusterQuorumCommand"],
> "stdout": "Report file location: C:\Windows\cluster\Reports\Create
> Cluster Wizard VSRVCLS on 2021.04.29
> VSRVCLS                                              Диск кластера 1
> "stdout_lines": ["Report file location:
> C:\Windows\cluster\Reports\Create Cluster Wizard VSRVCLS on
> 2021.04.29 At 16.17.18.mht" "Name                                                                                                          "----
> "VSRVCLS                 Диск кластера 1

Comment: I don't follow the actual problem you're facing (partially because you didn't include any error message); is it that the string literal `"Quorum"` doesn't match because `FileSystemLabel` is something else? Please do consider reading the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Comment: Hello @mdaniel! Label is matched. I attached error message, the problem is due to the language used . When I running script in Powershell ISE on local server, $CLuster_Quorum is "Диск кластера 1" and everything works. Ansible put "Cluster Disk 1"  in $CLuster_Quorum which cause error, because "Cluster Disk 1" doesn't exist in system due to language issue.

Comment: If a property is being localized like that, then surely there must be a more permanent identifier one can use that is not subject to localization. That said, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7770511 implies that perhaps the `domain.domain_admin`'s locale is not ru-RU as it sounds like your local server's account is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with **win_shell** module. I tried to use **ansible.windows.win_powershell** and it helped. Variable began contain symbols in language which I need.

Thanks for taking time!